# Is there anyway to add a route prefix to a single Action in a controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I want to be able to add a prefix to the path of only some endpoints within the same controller. i.e.

```
// Routes to api/[controller]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult<Response>> Get(Guid id) { ... }

// Routes to private/api/[controller]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]Request request) { ... }
```

I have tried it with a Convention but it doesnt seem to want to play nice with prefixes. Has anyone done this before or do I simply need to capitulate and stick it in its own Controller?

Comment: Add a route attribute to all endpoints and none to the controller?

Comment: Yeah thats what I am hoping to avoid. If thats the only way then thats the only way. It seems a little inelegant.

Comment: Then go for multiple Controllers. I see no problem with that. Typically they tend to be rather empty and just take request params and forward them to a service. How that bit of code is shared on Controllers shouldn't make to much of a difference.

Comment: Fair enough, if there is no way to do it. 

The Convention very nearly works its a shame I cant just decorate them with a PrivateAttribute. 

But you are right, sometimes its not worth the effort.